# Web scraping an element using beautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab an element from tradingview.com. Specifically [this link](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NEARUSD/). I want the price of a symbol of whatever link I give my program. I noticed when looking through the elements of the url, I can find the price of the stock here.

```
<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last">
    "3.065"
    <span class>57851</span>
</div>
```

When running this code below, I get this output.

```
#This will not run on online IDE
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
URL = "https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NEARUSD/"
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') # If this line causes an error, run 'pip install html5lib' or install html5lib
L = [soup.find_all(class_ = "tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last")] 
print(L)
```

output

```
[[<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"></div>]]
```

**How can I grab the entire price from this website? I would like the 3.065 as well as the 57851.**

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webpage's contents  are loaded dynamically by JavaScript. So you have to use an automation tool something like selenium or hidden API.

Here I use selenium with bs4 to grab the desired dynamic content.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
url= "https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NEARUSD/"
driver.get(url)   
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

price = soup.find('div',class_ = "tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last").get_text(strip=True)
print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
3.07525163
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the most common problem: page uses `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

---

Using `DevTool` I found it uses JavaScript to send `POST` (with some JSON data) and it gets fresh price.

```
import requests

payload = {
    "columns": ["market_cap_calc", "market_cap_diluted_calc", "total_shares_outstanding", "total_shares_diluted", "total_value_traded"],
    "range": [0, 1],
    "symbols": {"tickers": ["BINANCE:NEARUSD"]}
}

url = 'https://scanner.tradingview.com/crypto/scan'

response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
print(response.text)

data = response.json()
print(data['data'][0]["d"][1]/1_000_000_000)
```

Result:

```
{"totalCount":1,"data":[{"s":"BINANCE:NEARUSD","d":[2507704855.0467912,3087555230,812197570,1000000000,106737372.9550421]}]}

3.08755523
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems above code gives only `market cap`. And page uses `websocket` to get fresh price every few seconds.

```
wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=symbols%2FNEARUSD%2F&date=2022_10_17-11_33
```

And this would need more complex code.

Other answer (with Selenium) gives you correct value.

Comment: payload has `"columns": ["market_cap_calc", "market_cap_diluted_calc", "total_shares_outstanding", "total_shares_diluted", "total_value_traded"],` and I think result gives these values. I also compared values from POST requests in brewser with current price on page and it seems little different.

Comment: You are right, it is a tad off. Unfortunate.

Comment: maybe if use other value in `columns` then it could give correct value - but I don't know what column to use. But I have other idea - it seems it get data from `binance.com` and this page has [API](https://www.binance.com/en/binance-api), and maybe using API you could get price. You would have to check if API shares information about fresh price.

Comment: Tried that. For some reason, I can only find the price on binance that goes to two decimal places unlike multiple in tradingview